# NSIS: Unable to get JRE version from registry in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: registry, nsis

I'm using NSIS script to generate the windows installer for my Java project. In this installer, I want to check whether the computer has the right JRE version before proceeding.

This is my code snippet for getting the JRE version:-

```
ReadRegStr $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" "CurrentVersion"

# display $1 value for testing purpose
MessageBox MB_OK "Version: $1"
```

This code works fine in Windows XP, but I can't get it to work in Windows 7 64 bit... the version number is always blank. I check the registry, and I'm pretty sure the path is correct and "CurrentVersion" has a value.

Can anyone tell me what I do wrong here?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In NSIS, you can set the registry "mode" with [SetRegView](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.7.6)

Answer (score 2):

Is the installer 32 bit and the runtime 64 bit or vice versa? In that case you might get redirected to different registry nodes (inside HKLM/Software or HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node).

Answer (score 1):

The NSIS installer is a 32 bit program so it sees a different part of the registry.  This knowledge base article explains the difference in the registry on 64 bit Windows.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097

I'm not entirely sure if you can access the key you need from a 32 bit app or not.